# Make Rstudio works with custom compiled R on Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio

I instlled R 2.14 with R Commander via Ubuntu Software Center at first.

And then I installed Rstudio and it worked fine with R 2.14.

After a while, I wanted to use R 2.15 but failed compiling the R 2.15 source code.

Therefore, I tried "sudo apt-get build-dep r-base".
After that I compiled R 2.15 successfully, and installed R 2.15.

But, now Rstudio keeps reporting 
"R shared library (/usr/local/lib/R/lib/libR.so) not found. If this is a custom build of R, was it built with the --enable-R-shlib option?"

It seems that I should reinstall R 2.15 with option --enable-R-shlib.

But the problem is that how can I unstall R 2.15?

I tried "sudo apt-get autoremove r-base", but R 2.15 still works on my Ubuntu.

Any ideas on how I can make Rstudio works with custom compiled R?

Thanks,

Comment: Tried the RStudio support forum? This isn't it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

Briefly, I should use make uninstall to remove R 12.5.

Comment: Just recompiling and installing would overwritten the current install, which would have been fine.

Answer (score 1):

You're going about this in too-complicated a manner.

See the [README for Ubuntu binaries from  CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu) to get 2.15 binaries as proper `.deb` packages.

These will be in the path, have proper Depends: and just work, from command-line or via RStudio.